# Arranging 4 pages into one to save ink, space and paper

Tags: pdf, batch-file, openoffice.org

The plan is to convert a bunch(~100) of OpenOffice odp documents to PDF. That's not the big deal! However I need to reduce the number of PDF pages e.g. moving 4 sheets to one before exporting them to PDF. Is there a way like a batch program that does that for me?

Answer (score 3):

what you are looking for to do is called *imposition* and it needs to be performed on pdf resulting files

assuming any of your exported pdf pages is A4 size **(29.7x21cm)**, with

**Multivalent**

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355/Multivalent20060102.jar.html
  (latest free version with tools included, current has no tools in itself)

you can place 4 pages, (reducing their size to an A6 page: **14.8x10cm**) into an A4

```
java -cp path....to/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 2x2 -paper  A4 file.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, that's what I exactly searched for! Very helpful and convenient. Thanks a lot @Dingo!

Comment: you can perform 4-up imposition on all pdf with wildcard `java -cp path....to/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 2x2 -paper  A4 *.pdf`; resulting pdf will have *-up* in filename so you can easily filter to move in another folder

Comment: @Dingo Please reference the following rather than those file hosts unless as you remark it actually doesn't include the tools although I think they are included. Multivalent is at http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/ the latest being http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/multivalent/multivalent/Release20091027/Multivalent20091027.jar

Comment: latest multivalent.jar from sourceforge does not have the *tools* inside, as said, and very unfairly, project maintainer deleted older multivalent.jar builds from sourceforge servers, so I'm constrained to refer to other links to download latest multivalent.jar with tools

Comment: All: needless to say, be _very_ careful with using executable files downloaded from hosts such as these. @Dingo, have you tried getting these files hosted 'officially'?

Answer (score 0):

Along with Multivalent, as recommended by Dingo, there's also [jPdf Tweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/) which has a decent (but not great) GUI. You would want to use the "*Shuffle/N-up*" feature to get what you are trying to do.